# Combine two mysql queries with uneven columns

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql queries that I'd like to combine. I'm shame-posting here as I've tried many combinations to make it work but can't figure it out. I guess I've hit a ceiling in my query writing abilities. :(

Query #1

```
        SELECT 
        time_clock.id AS clock_id, 
        employees.first_name, employees.last_name, employees.nick_name, employees.pay_schedule, time_clock.comments, 
        employees.id AS employee_id, time_clock.punch_in, 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_clock.punch_in) AS punch_in_unix, 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_clock.punch_out) AS punch_out_unix, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time_clock.punch_in, time_clock.punch_out) AS time_spent
        FROM time_clock 
        JOIN employees ON employees.id = time_clock.employee_id 
        WHERE time_clock.id IN 
            (
            SELECT MAX(time_clock.id)
            FROM time_clock
            WHERE employees.pay_schedule='hourly'
            GROUP BY employee_id
            )
        ORDER BY last_name, first_name ASC
```

Query #2

```
        SELECT
        employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
        employees.id AS employee_id, 
        SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_clock.punch_out) - TIME_TO_SEC(time_clock.punch_in)) AS summed_seconds
        FROM time_clock 
        JOIN employees ON employees.id = time_clock.employee_id 
        WHERE YEAR(punch_in + interval 4 day) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND
        WEEK(punch_in + interval 4 day) = WEEK(CURDATE())
        GROUP BY employee_id
```

Each query functions fine on its own. The first query selects the latest time event for each employee. The second query sums the recorded time for each employee in the last pay period (weekly, from Wed. to Tues.).

I'd love to have one query do both: Select the latest time event for each employee and sum the time for those with time recorded in the last pay period. (I'm doing this to present an interface for keeping track of which employees are on overtime.)

Any help I can get would be fantastic. I've also been exploring combining the results as arrays in php to get what I want but that presents its own set of problems for me and I suspect isn't as efficient.

The output of Query #1 is like so:

[image]

The output of Query #2 looks like:

[image]

And this is essentially the output I'd like to be able to have:

[image]

Thank you for any help you can offer. My forehead is denting faster than the desk I'm banging it on.

-Matt

PS - One of my attempts to combine them is below. It seems to produce the most sane error out of all my attempts ("The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"), so I don't know how close it really is.

```
SELECT 
        time_clock.id AS clock_id, 
        employees.first_name, employees.last_name, employees.nick_name, employees.pay_schedule, time_clock.comments, 
        employees.id AS employee_id, time_clock.punch_in, 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_clock.punch_in) AS punch_in_unix, 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_clock.punch_out) AS punch_out_unix, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time_clock.punch_in, time_clock.punch_out) AS time_spent
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM time_clock 
            LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.id = time_clock.employee_id
            WHERE time_clock.id IN 
                (
                SELECT MAX(time_clock.id)
                FROM time_clock
                WHERE employees.pay_schedule='hourly'
                GROUP BY employee_id
                )

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
                employees.id AS employee_id, 
                SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_clock.punch_out) - TIME_TO_SEC(time_clock.punch_in)) AS summed_seconds
                FROM time_clock 
                LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.id = time_clock.employee_id 
                WHERE YEAR(punch_in + interval 4 day) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND
                      WEEK(punch_in + interval 4 day) = WEEK(CURDATE())
                GROUP BY employee_id
                ) as thing_one
        JOIN employees ON employees.id = time_clock.employee_id 
        ORDER BY last_name, first_name ASC
```

Comment: Your question is too messy for me to follow, but one hint would be that you _can_ do a `UNION` of two tables with a different number of columns, so long as you use placeholders for the extra columns in each table.

Comment: If I understood it right you just need to left join the first query with the second ON employee_id of both. And for the summed_seconds column a coalesce to 0 to solve the nulls. Can you do it from this hint?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Looks like Trung Duong had the same thinking you did, which seems to be working for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looks like a guy that just make my comment as an answer to get easy points... hehehehehe let it be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT     time_clock.id AS clock_id, 
           employee_lastest_event.first_name, 
           employee_lastest_event.last_name, 
           employee_lastest_event.nick_name, 
           employee_lastest_event.pay_schedule, 
           time_clock.comments, 
           time_clock.employee_id, 
           time_clock.punch_in, 
           UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_clock.punch_in)                              AS punch_in_unix,
           UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_clock.punch_out)                             AS punch_out_unix,
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, time_clock.punch_in, time_clock.punch_out) AS time_spent, 
           COALESCE(sum_period.summed_seconds, 0)                           AS summed_seconds 
FROM       time_clock 
           INNER JOIN 
            ( 
              SELECT     time_clock.employee_id, 
                         employees.first_name, 
                         employees.last_name, 
                         employees.nick_name, 
                         employees.pay_schedule, 
                         MAX(time_clock.id) AS clock_id 
              FROM       time_clock 
              INNER JOIN employees 
              ON         employees.id = time_clock.employee_id 
              WHERE      employees.pay_schedule='hourly' 
              GROUP BY   time_clock.employee_id ) employee_lastest_event 
           ON  (employee_lastest_event.clock_id = time_clock.id) 
           LEFT JOIN 
           ( 
              SELECT   time_clock.employee_id, Sum(time_to_sec(time_clock.punch_out) - time_to_sec(time_clock.punch_in)) AS summed_seconds
              FROM     time_clock 
              WHERE    year(time_clock.punch_in + INTERVAL 4 day) = year(curdate()) 
              AND      week(time_clock.punch_in + INTERVAL 4 day) = week(curdate()) 
              GROUP BY time_clock.employee_id ) sum_period 
            ON (sum_period.employee_id = time_clock.employee_id)
ORDER BY last_name, first_name ASC
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you so much! (There was a typo 7 lines from the last but once I found and corrected that it worked.)

Answer (score 0):

Just join both the queries using employee_id

```
SELECT clock_id,
table1.first_name,
table1.last_name,
nick_name,
pay_schedule,
comments,
table1.employee_id,
punch_in,
punch_in_unix,
punch_out_unix,
time_spent,
summed_seconds
(SELECT 
        time_clock.id AS clock_id, 
        employees.first_name, employees.last_name, employees.nick_name, employees.pay_schedule, time_clock.comments, 
        employees.id AS employee_id, time_clock.punch_in, 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_clock.punch_in) AS punch_in_unix, 
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_clock.punch_out) AS punch_out_unix, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time_clock.punch_in, time_clock.punch_out) AS time_spent
        FROM time_clock 
        JOIN employees ON employees.id = time_clock.employee_id 
        WHERE time_clock.id IN 
            (
            SELECT MAX(time_clock.id)
            FROM time_clock
            WHERE employees.pay_schedule='hourly'
            GROUP BY employee_id
            )) as table1,

(SELECT
        employees.first_name, employees.last_name,
        employees.id AS employee_id, 
        SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_clock.punch_out) - TIME_TO_SEC(time_clock.punch_in)) AS summed_seconds
        FROM time_clock 
        JOIN employees ON employees.id = time_clock.employee_id 
        WHERE YEAR(punch_in + interval 4 day) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND
        WEEK(punch_in + interval 4 day) = WEEK(CURDATE())
        GROUP BY employee_id
) as table2
WHERE table1.employee_id = table2.employee_id
```